# The provided registration token is not registered

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notification for iOS via Google cloud functions but it returns error that `The provided registration token is not registered`. But I've checked it by debugging my app and the FCM registration token is correct. After that I've tried to send push notification via Firebase console to single device by providing FCM token but it failed due to `Unregistered registration token`. How this happens because there is no issue with device FCM token?

Comment: Can you please add code for FCM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should be some careless mistake, you should make sure the things below:

1. The token is same with `-[FIRMessagingDelegate messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken]`
2. The `GoogleService-Info.plist` is [downloaded](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) from the same account with your Firebase push console.
3. Updated to the latest Firebase SDK.

From the Google Firebase [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors) are some description of your error `The provided registration token is not registered`.

> The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid
>   registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons,
>   including:
>
> - The client app unregistered itself from FCM.
> - The client app was automatically unregistered. This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback
>     Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - The registration token expired. For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for iOS
>     devices.
> - The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages. For all these cases, remove this registration token
>     and stop using it to send messages.

Comment: Yes problem is about with APNS token.

Comment: Oh ... I think the application was removed and installed again. Shall check this out. Thanks

Comment: what was the problem with APNS token and how to resolve? I have similar issue but no lead to resolve

Answer (score 1):

I also got a similar error. Something like this.

```
FirebaseMessagingError: The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.
```

**So I simply generated a new token and replaced it with the old one.**

And it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue and it turned out that our server was sending a bad notification payload for a certain use case.  When this happened, Firebase would send a return code of 400 and unregister the token.

The fix for us was to fix the use case sending the bad payload.  The error in our payload was due to "DeviceTokenNotForTopic".  Be sure to check that you aren't getting errors when posting notifications prior to when you get in this bad state.

Answer (score 0):

**I also got a similar error on the released build iOS device.**

```
The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.
```

I fixed it by reuploading correct **.p12 certificate** on the firebase messaging

**I got a mail from firebase support team:**

"In your case, please note that you can only upload up to 2 APN certificates. One for development and another for production. Since one of the APN certificates is invalid, you should delete the incorrect one. To be able to delete an APN certificate, the user must have an 'owner' permission/role. Upon checking, you don’t have enough permission to make this change.  I suggest you reach out to the project owner to request the necessary permission or to delete the APN certificate.

Just to add, As of I/O 2017, developers can use either auth keys or certs for their APNs. We recommend that you use auth keys because they are easier to configure and do not expire. If both cert and an auth key is uploaded, our server will use the auth key.

Our system can not validate auth keys like it does certificates. We do not have a way of validating that APNs will accept them without sending an actual message. With certs, we open a connection to APNs before accepting them, and if they are invalid APNs reject them and we can return the error to the user."